# Is good Idea Apply a generic common functions to all services using interfaces an abstracts?

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, design-patterns, interface

I am starting a new project using Spring Boot 3. We are still at an early stage of the project and still defining things. so, being said that. Here is my question:

**The problem I want to solve:** the service layer which is meant to handle all the business logic shares common functions among the entities, eg: CRUD functions and others.

**Proposal:** Create a Generic interface with all common functions. then: creates an Abstract class that will implement this interface and override; why an Abstract because I want to prevent the paint of adding new functions to the parent interface and going through all the implemented cases.

**Here is an example I implemented:**

```java
// Project stucture.
main-project
|-src
   |--main
       |-java
          |-com.project
               |-entities
               |-repositories
               |-service
               |    |-implementation    
               |-rest
```

**now**
We all know what is inside entities, repositories and rest package, here is my service package implementation:

**BaseCommonOperationInterface**

```java
public interface BaseCommonOperationInterface<E, V> {

  E createItemOf(V requestDto);
  E updateItemfrom(final Long identifier, V requestDto);
  void deleteItem(final Long identifier);
  Optional<E> findSingleRecordByIdentifier(Long skillDicCategoryId);
  List<E> listAllItems();
//more common function...
}
```

**BusinessBaseAbstract**

```java
puiblic abstract class BusinessBaseAbstract<E, V> implements BaseCommonOperationInterface<E, V>{
//Here override all methods from interface...
 @Override
  public List<E> listAllItems() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
//...
}
```

**DictionaryService**

```java
public interface DictionaryService implement BaseCommonOperationInterface<DictionaryEntity, DictionaryrequestDto>{}
```

**DictionaryServiveImpl**

```java
@RequieredArgConstructor
@Service
public class DictionaryServiveImpl extends BusinessBaseAbstract<DictionaryEntity, DictionaryrequestDto> implements DictionaryService{
private final DictionaryRepository dictionaryRepository;

//I can override eather single common function or all of them
@override
public List<DictionaryEntity> listAllItems(){
 return dictionaryRepository.findAll()
}
// all the methods I need overrided here...
}
```

**DictionaryController**

```java
@RestController
public class DictionaryController{

private final DictionaryService service;

@GetMapping("/dictionary")
public List<DictionarEntity> getAllofThem(){
return service.listAllItems();
}
//Here rest of implementations...
}
```

Why no call the DictionaryRepository from the controller beacause we want to keep the Rest Controller clean as much as possible and delegate all business logic to Service package.

Does this pattern make sense?
are there advantages and disavantages?
are there others pattern that I can apply to abstract common function?

Comment: IMHO having a service just frontiend-ending a repository (and not adding anything to that) is bad practice, adding code for no reason.   Instead, the repository can be thought of AS a service - ie no problem having the controller call the repository directly.   For further discussion, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306890/is-it-bad-practice-that-a-controller-calls-a-repository-instead-of-a-service

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good idea.

Having a number of classes which implement an interface is a good idea when you want to use instances of classes which implement the interface without knowing their concrete class.

If you had a collection of all your `XxxServiceImpl` classes, and wanted to run a method from `BaseCommonOperationInterface` on each of them, then the interface would be useful. But that's not typically how services are used -- they are injected explicitly into the controller classes which need them.

Having a common interface means that when you add a method to one service you need to add it to all -- but perhaps the services are different.

You propose an abstract base class so that you can have a no-operation implementation for some services, but this just makes your services confusing -- should we expect calling this method to do something or not? Users of the services will wonder why a particular service has a method on it which it doesn't need, not knowing that the interface requires it, and the implementation does nothing.

Finally, if you do have a good reason for enforcing that a method exists on all your services, then yes, use an interface, but *don't* put an empty implementation in an abstract class.

Without that abstract class, you will be forced to consider: what implementation does this service need for the new method? If a default implementation exists, ir will be very easy to miss thinking about a service when a new method is added.